# How do I create an "origin" repository for an exisiting project in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: git, visual-studio

I have numerous projects/solutions that I would like to get under source control. I have set up  a shared folder on our network that I would like to use as the origin.
I understand how to put an existing project under source control and commit to the local/master repository but what I can't find is a way to create the origin repository from within VS2015. Can this be done? Or do I need to do it from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set up git repository and start git daemon.
Once you have the repository you add the url to your local project.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository

```
git remote add origin <url>
```

Comment: I am using a UNC share not a git daemon. It works if I create the origin repos from command line, I just want to do it from within VS